# SQL Server Create Table gives error that object '' already exists when it doesn't

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, create-table

Sorry if this looks like a duplicate but I cannot find an answer to my situation. I am trying to create table `cardissuedates` in database `NBFP`.

Here is my create statement:

```
USE NBFoodPantry

CREATE TABLE cardissuedates 
(
    clientid char(36) NOT NULL,
    issuedate date NOT NULL

    CONSTRAINT cardissuedates 
       PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (clientid ASC)
           WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                 IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                 ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I get this error:

> Msg 2714, Level 16, State 5, Line 33
>   There is already an object named 'cardissuedates' in the database.
>
> Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 33
>   Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

The table does not exist in the `NBFB` database and I cannot find it when I check master and NBFB.

I have tried

```
select * 
from sys.all_objects
where name like '%ca%'
order by 1

select * 
from sys.tables
where name like 'c%'
order by 1

select * 
from sys.all_columns
where name like 'c%'
order by 1
```

I even created a new database and executed this create statement, with the new database name in the USE statement. Same error.

I have stopped all services exited out of SSMS. Nothing seems to work.
I do not know where to look any more.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried running DROP TABLE cardissuedates to confirm that the table does not exist?

Comment: the error is int the creation of the constraint, not the table, see my answer below

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you are giving the primary key the same name as the table, this is not allowed as both are schema scoped objects and multiple objects can't have the same `schema_name.object_name`. You can do this instead:

```
CREATE TABLE cardissuedates ( 
    clientid char(36) NOT NULL, 
    issuedate date NOT NULL CONSTRAINT 
    pk_cardissuedates PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( clientid ASC )
    WITH (
        PAD_INDEX = OFF, 
        STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
        IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
        ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
        ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, 
        FILLFACTOR = 90
    ) ON [PRIMARY] 
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I just added the prefix PK_ to the constraint

Comment: #Massimiliano Carosi -- Thank you.  That worked.  I knew I must be missing something simple.  Again Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the subject. I encountered a similar situation where I was creating a simple “employees” table and I received the same error message.

However, the table was not listed in the “Table” folder in my database. I was not applying any constraints on the table. It was just 3 columns; “colID INT”, “fName VARCHAR(20)”, and “LastFourSSN INT”. That’s it, just a simple table, but still I got the error message:

*There is already an object named 'employees' in the database.*

In my situation, it was because I had a SYNONYM named “employees”. Once I dropped the SYNONYM, all worked fine.